# Robot Framework Webdriver Manager - Not able to get driver path when executed with other keywords

Tags: python, robotframework, webdriver-manager

I am using webdriver-manager under Robot Framework to automatically manage drivers. I have created a python library where method is defined to get the driver path (see the code snippet below):

```
#BrowserDriverManager.py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
def get_browser_driver_path():
    driver_path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
    return  driver_path
```

I have imported python library under Robot Framework resource and created a keyword for opening application (see the code snippet below).

```
Open application using browser
    ${url}=    Generate URL for web request via browser
    ${driverPath}=      get_browser_driver_path
    Create Webdriver    ${BROWSER}      executable_path=${driverPath}
    Go To   ${url}
```

Now when I am executing test case (under Robot Framework) with only one keyword "Open application using browser" then test executed successfully. See the Success attachment.[image]
However if in the test case there are few keywords before "Open application using browser" then test failed under "Open application using browser". See the Failure attachment.[image]

Failure is happening during the execution of get_browser_driver_path method. I am not sure if keywords executed before having any impact.
Does anyone faced this kind of issue before where keyword execution worked fine in isolation but not in group?

Comment: what python version and OS?

Comment: @rasjani its python 3.7 with Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Error is most likely from your environment variables as the error is `ValueError: unknown locale: en-US` which python doesn't seem to recognize.

I have something like these in my environment:

```
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
```